# Necessity of <? super T> type in Collections.copy

Tags: java, generics

Collections.copy method signature is,

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

Just wondering is it necessary for the dest type to be `<? super T>` and not just `<T>`?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  simpleCopy(new ArrayList<Number>(), new ArrayList<Number>());
  simpleCopy(new ArrayList<Number>(), new ArrayList<Integer>());
}

public static <T> void simpleCopy(Collection<T> dest, Collection<?  extends T> src)
{
   for (T element : src)
     dest.add(element);
}
```

Comment: Confusingly, your `simpleCopy` reverses the parameters.

Comment: @Michael, corrected it.